# Python pandas merge multiple dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with structure like that :

| date | X1 | date | X2 | date | X3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/1970 | 5 | 01/01/1970 | 1 | 02/01/71 | 10 |
| 05/01/1970 | 15 | 02/01/1970 | 5 | 04/01/71 | 11 |
| 06/01/1970 | 15.1 | 03/01/1970 | 5.5 | 05/01/71 | 11 |
| 07/01/1970 | 15.1 | 04/01/1970 | 5.5 | 06/01/71 | 11 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

it could be generate with this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date1': [pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01'),
                        pd.to_datetime('1970-01-05'),
                        pd.to_datetime('1970-01-06'),
                        pd.to_datetime('1970-01-07')], 
                        'X1': [5, 15,15.1, 15.1], 
                'date2': [pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01'),
                        pd.to_datetime('1970-01-02'),
                        pd.to_datetime('1970-01-03'),
                        pd.to_datetime('1970-01-04')], 
                        'X2': [1, 5,5.1, 1.1],
                'date3': [pd.to_datetime('1970-01-02'),
                        pd.to_datetime('1970-01-04'),
                        pd.to_datetime('1970-01-05'),
                        pd.to_datetime('1970-01-06')], 
                        'X3': [10, 11,11, 11],
                        })
```

From this dataframe, I would like to get a dataframe like that :

| date | X1 | X2 | X3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/1970 | 5 | 1 | na |
| 02/01/1970 | na | 5 | 10 |
| 03/01/1970 | na | 5.5 | na |
| 04/01/1970 | na | 5.5 | 11 |
| 05/02/1970 | 15 | na | 11 |
| 06/03/1970 | 15.1 | na | 11 |
| 07/04/1970 | 15.1 | na | na |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Could you explain better? And please show proof of work

Comment: is this more clear now ?

Comment: Hi @Jacques can you share a sample dataframe please, the data in raw text format will be good

Answer (score 0):

You can break the dataframe (df) into 3 different dataframes, and then append them.

```
df1 = df[['date','X1']]
df2 = df[['date','X2']]
df3 = df[['date','X3']]

intermediate = df1.append(df2, ignore_index =True)
output = intermediate.append(df3, ignore_index = True)
```

You could chain the two commands together too

Comment: But I don't know how many colonms I have. It depends on the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.concat(
    [
        df.iloc[0-1, :].rename({"X1": "X1"}, , axis=1),
        df.iloc[2-3, :].rename({"X2": "X1"}, , axis=1),
        df.iloc[4-5, :].rename({"X3": "X1"}, , axis=1),
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date1': [pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01'),
                        pd.to_datetime('1970-01-05'),
                        pd.to_datetime('1970-01-06'),
                        pd.to_datetime('1970-01-07')], 
                        'X1': [5, 15,15.1, 15.1], 
                'date2': [pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01'),
                        pd.to_datetime('1970-01-02'),
                        pd.to_datetime('1970-01-03'),
                        pd.to_datetime('1970-01-04')], 
                        'X2': [1, 5,5.1, 1.1],
                'date3': [pd.to_datetime('1970-01-02'),
                        pd.to_datetime('1970-01-04'),
                        pd.to_datetime('1970-01-05'),
                        pd.to_datetime('1970-01-06')], 
                        'X3': [10, 11,11, 11],
                        })

mylist = []
mydataframes = []

#Get the indexes of all the columns starting with "date" and put them on a list
for i in df.columns:
    if i.startswith('date'):
        idx = df.columns.get_loc(i)
        mylist.append(idx)
        
#Split into multiple DataFrames based on the previous indexes list and put each one of them in a list of DataFrames
for y in mylist:
    my = df.iloc[:, y:(y+2)]
    mydataframes.append(my)

#Manipulate each new DataFrame and finally concatenate them altogether for the final result        
for i in range(len(mydataframes)):
    mydataframes[i] = mydataframes[i].rename(columns=lambda x: 'date' if x.startswith('date') else x)
    mydataframes[i].set_index('date', inplace =True)

result = pd.concat(mydataframes, axis=1)

result

            X1     X2   X3
date            
1970-01-01  5.0   1.0  NaN
1970-01-02  NaN   5.0  10.0
1970-01-03  NaN   5.1  NaN
1970-01-04  NaN   1.1  11.0
1970-01-05  15.0  NaN  11.0
1970-01-06  15.1  NaN  11.0
1970-01-07  15.1  NaN  NaN
```

A quite quick approach. I don't know if that's the more efficient. Your could remove the dates from the index if you don't want them there (All this stuff because you mentioned the dataframe you provided is only a use case and you dont know how many columns you will have everytime).

My question is do you have them already split or all in one DataFrame? I answered thinking you have them already in one big DataFrame. Because from the example you provided it seemed like you created the DataFrame.

If you have them already split skip the first part, set the same index on each (the date) and concatenate.